# Budgie: Keyboard shortcut 'show desktop'

Tags: shortcut-keys, desktop-environments, budgie

How do I quickly minimize all windows to see the desktop in Ubuntu Budgie?

I tried <kbd>Super (Windows)</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> but nothing happens.

I’m using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut for this action might be disabled in your keyboard settings.
But you can enable it.

- From menu, navigate to *Preferences* → *Settings* → *Keyboard* or search for the "keyboard" keyword from dash.
- On the right side you can see all configured keyboard shortcuts.
- Scroll down and find the *Navigation* section and double click on *Hide all normal windows*.
- There, you will be asked to map a key combination to the action. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then click *Set*.
- Now you can toggle hiding and showing all windows using that shortcut.